# Use Windows XP as a print server for a Windows 7 client

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, drivers, printing, print-server

I have a older printer (Dell 944) that does not have drivers supported by windows 7.  I hooked the printer up to a XP computer (actually in ESXI) and have it printing.  I shared this printer, but when I connect to in from windows 7 it says driver not found.

Is there a method to print using a different driver in order to print from the windows 7 machine?  My end goal is to have this be a print server that I can access over the internet and print to.

**Resolution:**
I resolved the problem by using google cloud print.  I installed the server on the print server and can print from the print client on my computers.

Comment: Have you tried [downloading](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-944/drivers) and installing the drivers on the Windows 7 machine?

Comment: @CharlieRB OP said "that does not have drivers supported by windows 7"

Comment: Didn't exactly type what I was thinking. :-) ...Have you tried installing the Windows Vista drivers on Windows 7 to see if they will work. Sometimes the drivers are similar enough to work.

Comment: Agree with above. Depending on your bitness (64 or 32). You may be able to get away with using the matching windows xp or vista driver for it

Comment: I resolved the problem through alternate software.  Please close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Even with a shared printer, the client still needs a proper driver. AFAIK the setup you have now will only work with a PostScript (or maybe a PCL?) printer.

If your printer support PS out of the box, you're in luck. If not, there seems to be a way to share a non-ps printer as a postscript one, by installing GhostScript and some other tools. I found a (rather lengthy) description on how to do that. So rather than copying the entire story, I'm posting just a link.

http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/Turn-any-non-PostScript-printer-into-a-PostScript-printer